# Help in proving homeomorphic map for topological cylinder

Tags: general-topology

I have understood that a cylinder can be obtained from a square by gluing a pair of its opposite sides.

Mathematically if we take $X=[0, 1]$ X $[0,1]$ with equivalence relation ~ such that

$(s,0)$ ~ $(s,1)$ and $(s,t)$ ~ $(s,t)$ for $s,t$ $\neq$ $0,1$

Then $X$$/$~ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ X $I$ ,where $I=[0,1]$, by mapping $[(s,t)]$ to $(e^{2\pi is},t)$

I know that the continuity can be proved by observing that the composition map $fo\pi$, where $\pi$ is the map from $X$ to $X$$/$~ , is continuous.

MAIN PROBLEM: I am having a hard time in writing other mathematical details (bijection and continuity of inverse map) which are required to show the homeomorphism.

If someone could give me proper mathematical proof then it would be really helpful. Then i will write other construction (like cone, mobius band, torus) by myself.

Comment: I think you made a mistake either in the equivalence relation or in the definition of $\pi$ as $\pi(0,1) = (e^{2\pi i 0},1) = (e^{2\pi i 1},1) = \pi(1,1)$ but $(0,1)$ is not equivalent to $(1,1)$ which shows that $\pi$ is not injective.

Comment: @Lassadar That is not a mistake. The map $\pi$ is not injective because $[x]=[y]$ does not imply $x=y$ while defining the quotient topology, it is surjective. That is the definition.

Comment: sorry I meant the homeomorphism and not the projection, replace $\pi$ by $f$ in the comment above. This is then supposed to be injective.
The projection identifies the border of the square corresponding to the second variable but $f$ then "glues together" the border corresponding to the first variable.

Comment: @Lassadar It would be really helpful if you could provide me proper proof of it. Because the more i am reading it the more i am getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First redefine your homeomorphism $f:X/\sim \rightarrow S^1 \times I$, $[s,t] \mapsto (e^{2\pi i t},s)$ (notice that $s$ and $t$ are switched. For an intuitive reason why this change is necessary imagine gluing opposite sides of a square ($I\times I$) together to get a cylinder. Now in order for this to be injective (i.e. we don't loose any information) we need to identify the glued sides via the relation. In your proposed homeomorphism you didn't glue together the sides that were identified but the other ones which made your map not injective.

You managed to show that this map is continuous.
Now we get injectivity by applying the definitions:
$$f(s,t)=f(s',t') \Leftrightarrow (e^{2\pi i t}, s) = (e^{2\pi i t'}, s') \Leftrightarrow s=s', t = t' + k, k\in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow [s,t] \sim [s',t']$$
where the last implication holds because the only way to get $t=t'+k$ is if $t=1$ and $t'=0$ or the other way round. This shows injectivity.
To show surjectivity try to find an inverse function which you then also show to be continuous.

As a side note: there is more than one way to parametrize $S^1$. You chose the complex unit circle. This works but I think the proof (in particular the inverse function) would be a bit simpler if you chose to parametrize $S^1$ by $[0,2\pi)$ (or even $[0,1)$) which stands for the angle. This lets you skip the exponential function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful. And yeah you were right, i made the mistake in defining homeomorphism.